# get mysql results by highest count

Tags: mysql, count

I have a table with fields:

`id`, `albumid`, `userid`, `keywords` where keywords is `varchar` and can be more than one by delimteter eg : one,two,three

I want to get the top 10 results of the most popular keyword but not by the same user
I currently use this but not sure if its correct:

```
 $tableName = $db->nameQuote('#__mytable');

 $sql = "SELECT `id`,`albumid`,`userid`,`keywords`, COUNT(keywords) AS popular FROM ".$tableName." GROUP BY `userid` HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ORDER BY popular DESC LIMIT ".$lim0.",".$lim;

 $db->setQuery($sql);
```

Is the following code correct. Im not sure if im getting the keyword with most duplicate entries...

Comment: Is keywords really a comma-separated string? COUNT() doesn't count the number of entries in a string, it's used to count the number of rows with the same key columns from a GROUP BY clause. MySQL doesn't have a built-in function to count the number of items in a comma-separated string. You should move this into another table, so there can be a row for each keyword, and then you can count them.

Comment: Yes it is. The current sql does give me results, i just didnt know if they were accurate in giving me by keywords.

Comment: Id like to know what this query is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query on for size, I just fudged around your groupings, and using DISTINCT userid as the counting metric

```
"SELECT `id`,`albumid`,`keywords`, COUNT(DISTINCT userid) AS popularity FROM ".$tableName." GROUP BY `keywords` HAVING popularity >= 1 ORDER BY popularity DESC LIMIT ".$lim0.",".$lim;
```

However, if your keywords column is comma delimited, this query will NOT work. This query operates on the fact that each record has a single keyword entry